# Regex, how to disallow leading zeros in whole numbers and allow one leading zero in fractions?

Tags: regex

The `^[0-9]{1,12}((\\.|,)[0-9]{0,2})?$` regex works ok, except I do not want it two match it against a case, where there are two leading zeros. How to write it?

This shouldn't be allowed:

```
0011
00,1
01,11
02 etc.
```

but this is OK `0,22`, `0`

Comment: the title states two leading 0, but `02` is not allowed, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I have corrected the title.

Comment: The title now says plain `0` must not be considered valid. Is that intentional?

Comment: Plain zero is perfectly OK. By leading zeros in whole numbers I meant for example `01`. A plain zero is a number in itself and I do not consider it a leading zero, as a part of a number made up of other numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing

```
^[0-9]{1,12}
```

by

```
^[1-9][0-9]{0,11}
```

will force number to start with a digit between 1 and 9 included

following question edit, to accept `0,22`:

```
^(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,11})((\\.|,)[0-9]{0,2})?$
```

Comment: I have clarified the questions. One zero is allowed in case of example `0,22`.

Comment: updated my answer adding `(0|`, also fixed {1,11} with {0,11} so that one digit can be accepted